# C++ How to do 2 Sort and merge result into 1

Tags: c++

Parent Class:

```
Character
```

Sub class:

```
Elf
Human
```

I have a variable which is

```
int myScore;
string myType;
```

so what i did was to sort by myType then sort by ascending score

means if i got record like this

```
[1] Human, 99
[2] Elf, 91
[3] Elf, 99
[4] Human, 99
```

If sort it will be

```
[1] Human, 90 
[2] Human, 99
[3] Elf, 91
[4] Elf, 99
```

I heard before the merge function that can merge 2 sort into 1.

But how do i use it.

What i did for now is

At character.cpp

```
struct sort_by_score
{
    static bool operator()(Character* x, Character* y)
    {
        return x->getScore() < y->getScore();
    }
};
```

At main.cpp

I did this

```
int main()
{
Character *chara[100];
vector<Character*> sortVector;

//some input of value here.. assuming now got 4 pointers to object, 2 human 2 elf. 

sortVector.clear();
sortVector.assign(chara,chara + characterCounter);

//here i got question on how to sort by Human Then Elf

//2nd sort is sort by score
sort(sortVector.begin(), sortVector.end(), sort_by_score());

for (int i=0;i<characterCounter;i++)
{
cout << sortVector.toDisplay() << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

**Thanks for all help!!**

Comment: Why are you using pointers instead of references?

Comment: What is now the type of your vector? I see `Character` in your description, `Shape` in your implementation of the `operator<` and `ShapeTwoD` in your main-code.

Comment: sorry typo. on shape and character

Comment: But how do you compare `Character*`s using `operator()(Shape*,Shape*)?` Or does Character inherit from Shape?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this very easy with lambdas (C++0x/11):

```
vector<Character> v = ...;

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Character &lhs,const Character & hs){
    return lhs.getType() == rhs.getType() ? lhs.getScore() < rhs.getScore()
                                          : lhs.getType() < lhs.getType();
});
```

Or for pointers:

```
vector<Character*> v = ...;

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Character *lhs,const Character * hs){
    return lhs->getType() == rhs.getType() ? lhs->getScore() < rhs->getScore()
                                           : lhs->getType() < lhs->getType();
});
```

---

I couldn't find a "criteria combiner" so I wrote one on my own. This should work:

```
template<class T, class First, class Second>
class combine {
    First first;
    Second second;
public:
    bool operator()(const T & lhs, const T & rhs) const {
        if(first(lhs, rhs)) return true;
        if(first(rhs, lhs)) return false;
        return second(lhs, rhs);
    }
};
```

With two basic comparison functors

```
struct less_type
{
    static bool operator()(const Character & lhs, const Character & rhs) {
        return lhs.getType() < rhs.getType();
    }
};
struct less_score
{
    static bool operator()(const Character & lhs, const Character & rhs) {
        return lhs.getScore() < rhs.getScore();
    }
};
```

this can be used like the following:

```
vector<Character*> v = ...;

sort(v.begin(),v.end(), combine<Character,less_type,less_score>());
```

This will also work without support for C++0x lambdas.